# How to deploy multiple docker containers through one port, and have access between them?

Tags: reactjs, docker, iis, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I´m facing some issues related to the deployment of a dockerized application. The problem is that I have few ports on my server, so to deploy this dockerized app I have to use port 80. However, this app has 3 containers (frontend-react, backend-python, database-Mongo), and each one has a specific port to expose its service. It works in local, but when I use a reverse proxy (IIS) to expose the frontend container (https://VM_IP -> VM_IP:1000), the process cant find the backend and database information (because they are in local server, and they are not exposed through IIS). So, is it possible to setup a network inside VM (to connect back-front-db), then expose only one port (frontend) in order to access to the full service?
Thanks for your help...

I tried IIS as reverse proxy, connecting each port from services to a specific path in my IP address. But, I'm not sure if it is correct, or if it is possible to solve this with a docker network

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your problem seems complicated, I suggest you  open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, about IIS reverse proxy you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).